# How to subclass a WPF ComboBox to add an extra button

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, custom-controls

I saw a similar question and hoped for a solution, but simply giving an advice to subclass the ComboBox is not enough for me. I need it in small spoons...

The case is I need an extra button on my special comboBox for adding new records to the item list. I have this as an UserControl today but it doesn't look good and I need more controls on my views, so I started making a custom control trying to extend ComboBox.

I didn't get far... Please lend me a hand... :)

My code so far:

```
public class ComboBoxWithAdd : ComboBox
{
    static ComboBoxWithAdd()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ComboBoxWithAdd), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ComboBoxWithAdd)));
    }
}
```

In Generic.xaml I have this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ComboBoxWithAdd}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">        
</Style>
```

Comment: Actually, this sounds like a good situation for a custom control rather than a subclass of `ComboBox`. Could you explain the in more detail why you've chosen to go this route and abandon enhancing the custom control? What about subclassing the custom control?

Comment: @Frustrated - A class you derive from ComboBox is a custom control. What is it you're advising?

Comment: @John Bowen: Sorry, more specifically: I meant a custom control in the sense of a class that is a subclass of `Control` and whose appearance and layout is manipulated through the forms designer. If I'm not mistaken, VisualStudio usually calls these classes UserControls.

Comment: @Frustrated: I did the UserControl route but I want to improve, and to me a Custom Control is much cleaner and much more a drop in replacement for the standard ComboBox. Yeah, I could expose all properties and events of the ComboBox in my User Control, but honestly that seems like much work.

Comment: @Frustrated - UserControls are classes derived from UserControl which are usually made up of a XAML and code-behind file which are partial classes of each other and compiled together at runtime. You can also do this with other control types, but it's not as common. They are easy to load and change in a designer but lose a lot of flexibility, like the ability to re-template. Custom control commonly refers to any class that is derived from Control or its descendants and is loosely linked to its UI by means of a ControlTemplate that can be changed even at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When making the decision to create a custom control you need to determine whether you need to add actual behavior or just UI. Just adding a button can be done by just customizing the ControlTemplate. It sounds like you want a button that causes an action that will update the Items of the ComboBox which would point to the direction you started down of deriving a control from ComboBox. You'll need to add a few things on the code and XAML side. In your Style you'll need to add a Setter for the ControlTemplate and start with a copy of the default template for ComboBox (I usually do this with Blend but there are other sources out there). You can then add in your new Button wherever you want it in the template.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ComboBoxWithAdd}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ComboBoxWithAdd}">
                ... copy of default template with your modifications
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

There are a few different ways you could connect the button but the most robust is to use a command that you can bind to in your control code. You can declare your own RoutedCommand in your control code later but to get started just use a built in one.

```
public ComboBoxWithAdd()
{
    CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.New, NewExecutedMethod));
}
```

Then in the NewExecutedMethod just add whatever logic you want to do the actual action to add an item (probably working with the ComboBox's Items/ItemsSource). To connect the button up just set `Command="ApplicationCommands.New"`. There's a lot more that can be done with a custom control but this should get you started.

Comment: I think this is the best answer I could get, but I realize that the ComboBox template is too complicated for my head at this time. I'm not giving up, but continues with other stuff and will try this again at a later time.

Comment: rozon, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Rozon, You can manipulate the Combobox from the code behind like this without creating a complex template:

```
public class CustomComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        Grid grid = WpfHelper.FindAllChildrenByName<Grid>(this, "MainGrid").SingleOrDefault() as Grid;
        if (grid != null)
        {
            grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Content = "test";
            button.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 2);
            grid.Children.Add(button);
        }
    } 
}
```

WpfHelper is just a class which finds a visual child by its name. Notice that this might break easily if the standard control template of the combobox is changed and MainGrid is renamed.

Comment: Cool. I didn't know the WpfHelper until now. I can see how this easily can break though, but I can also think of several other uses for that function. Thanks! :)

Comment: I think you can also do `var grid = GetTemplateChild( "MainGrid" ) as Grid;` if you don't have access to the WpfHelper.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the UserControl that you created by adding one more button and grouped them to make a user control and exposing the required events and commands.

Custom control is not advisable.

But, if you have requirement like that. Here we go:
1) You need to derive the control for what you are trying to extend the capability.
2) You need to create a default Template for the control. [Generic.Xaml]

Rest is your customization.
But, one advantage is you could get a easily Skinnable control.

HTH